# UNNotificationAction doesn't dismiss after choice

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase to send remote messages, like so:

AppDelegate (pseudo code):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) {granted, error in            
        let actionWithText = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "actionWithText", title: "Action with text", options: [.foreground], textInputButtonTitle: "Send", textInputPlaceholder: "Placeholder")
        let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "action", title: "Action without text", options: [.foreground])
        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "category", actions: [actionWithText, action], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if response.actionIdentifier == "actionWithText" {
        if let textResponse = response as? UNTextInputNotificationResponse {
            let textResponse = textResponse.userText
        }
    }

    if response.actionIdentifier == "action" {
        print("action received")
    }

    completionHandler()
}
```

The notifications are sent when the app is in the background (only when the Phone app is active, after picking up a call).

Receiving the notifications works fine, I can see both Actions and make a selection. After selection, the app comes to the foreground. However, the notification does not dismiss. I have tried using `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()` in multiple places (also in the didReceive handler), but the notification never disappears. I have found many issues on Stack Overflow with `removeAllDeliveredNotifications` (or `getDeliveredNotifications`) in recent iOS versions.

I have tried removing `.foreground` as an option, this does dismiss the notification (after selecting an action). But obviously does not bring my app to the foreground, which is the intended functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this method

```
func didReceive(_ response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler completion: @escaping (UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption) -> Void) {

    if response.actionIdentifier == "Clear" {
        completion(.dismiss)
        print("Clear. It will dismiss the notification")
    }else if (response.actionIdentifier == "Next"){
        completion(.doNotDismiss)
        print("Next. It will not dismiss the notification")
    }
}
```